# Struts2 modifying an object with arraylist of objects

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have an object in my Action class which contains an arraylist of objects internally, I am trying to create a CRUD screen for this object. My Action Class and bean are given below,

```
/**
 * @author rohit
 *
 */
public class IRFeedMgmtAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<IRFeeds>,SessionAware,ServletRequestAware {

private static org.apache.log4j.Logger log = Logger.getLogger(IRFeedMgmtAction.class);

private HttpServletRequest request;

private Map session;

private IRAccountsDAO acctsDAO;

private IRFeeds feed = new IRFeeds();

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport#execute()
 */
public String execute()
{
    return "success";
}

/**
 * @return
 */
public String add()
{
    IRUser user  = (IRUser) session.get("user");

    List<IRAccountUsers> twtUsers =  acctsDAO.getTwitterAcctByOrgId(user.getOrgId());
    feed.setTwtAccts(prepareTwitterAccounts(twtUsers));

    return "addFeed";
}

/**
 * @return
 */
public String save()
{
    IRFeeds fd = getFeed();
    ArrayList<IRFeedAccts> twtAccts = fd.getTwtAccts();

    System.err.println(fd.getFeedUrl());

    for (Iterator iterator = twtAccts.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) 
    {
        IRFeedAccts irFeedAccts = (IRFeedAccts) iterator.next();
        System.err.println(irFeedAccts.getNumber());
    }

    return "saved";
}

/**
 * @return 
 * 
 */
private ArrayList<IRFeedAccts> prepareTwitterAccounts(List<IRAccountUsers> twtUsers)
{
    ArrayList<IRFeedAccts> twtAccts = new ArrayList<IRFeedAccts>();
    IRAccountUsers twtUser = null;
    IRFeedAccts feedAccnt = null;
    for (Iterator iterator = twtUsers.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
    {
        twtUser = (IRAccountUsers) iterator.next();

        feedAccnt = new IRFeedAccts();
        feedAccnt.setAccountId(twtUser.getSocialId());
        feedAccnt.setPic(twtUser.getPic());
        feedAccnt.setName(twtUser.getTwtUsrName());
        feedAccnt.setNumber(30);

        twtAccts.add(feedAccnt);
    }

    return twtAccts;
}
```

MY BEAN

```
public class IRFeeds  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private Integer feedId;
 private Integer campId;
 private String feedUrl;
 private boolean active;
 private Date createdOn;
 private Date updatedOn;
 private String createdBy;

 private ArrayList<IRFeedAccts> twtAccts; 

 private ArrayList<IRFeedAccts> fbAccts;

 private ArrayList<IRFeedAccts> fbPages;
```

MY JSP FILE

```
<s:iterator value="#session.fd.twtAccts" status="twtAcct">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="width: 48px; float: left;"><img src="<s:property value="pic" />" /></div>
                    <div style="text-align: left;"><s:property value="name" /></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <s:textfield name="number"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" /> 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <s:textfield name="signature"/> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            </s:iterator>
```

Now my problem is when the value of the beans in the arraylist is modified in the JSP, the same doesn't reach the action class save method. The value remains the same.

Regards,
Rohit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve this issue

```
<s:iterator id="twtFeedAccts" value="twtFeedAccts" status="twtAcct">
            <tr>
                <td width="250">
                    <img src="<s:property  value="%{twtFeedAccts[#twtAcct.index].pic}" />"  width="25px" height="25px"  />
                        <s:property  value="%{twtFeedAccts[#twtAcct.index].name}" />

                </td>   
                <td width="200">
                    <s:textfield id="twtFeedAccts[%{#twtAcct.index}].number" name="twtFeedAccts[%{#twtAcct.index}].number" value="%{twtFeedAccts[#twtAcct.index].number}" />
                </td>
                <td width="200">
                    <s:select id="twtFeedAccts[%{#twtAcct.index}].cycle" name="twtFeedAccts[%{#twtAcct.index}].cycle" value="%{twtFeedAccts[#twtAcct.index].cycle}"
                     label="Select a month"  list="#{'2':'2 hrs','4':'4 hrs', '6':'6 hrs', '12':'12 hrs', '24':'24 hrs'}" />
                </td>
                <td width="250">
                    <s:textfield id="twtFeedAccts[%{#twtAcct.index}].signature" name="twtFeedAccts[%{#twtAcct.index}].signature" value="%{twtFeedAccts[#twtAcct.index].signature}" size="40"/>
                </td>
                <td width="50">
                    <s:checkbox id="twtFeedAccts[%{#twtAcct.index}].selected" name="twtFeedAccts[%{#twtAcct.index}].selected" value="%{twtFeedAccts[#twtAcct.index].selected}"  />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </s:iterator>
```

When you submit the form the beans will go populated.

Regards,
Rohit

Comment: what if the bean has got a list in itself, then only traversal of that list is possible, but what about saving that list within a bean on form submission ?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.ziddu.com/download/13531199/IteratorOverObjects.zip.html) is a working example(Netbeans 6.9 project) illustrating how to iterate over an array or list of objects.

Also, how to submit the form such that the list of objects gets re-created on submission.

Simply resolve the references and get going.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue:

**My JSP:**

```
<s:iterator value="feedbackFor" var="feedbackFor" status="stat">
<tr>
<td><s:label> <s:property value="feedbackFor" /></s:label> </td>


<td><s:label><s:property value="empName"/></s:label></td>
<s:hidden name="feedbackFor[%{#stat.index}].feedbackBy" value="%{feedbackBy}"></s:hidden>
<s:hidden name="feedbackFor[%{#stat.index}].feedbackFor" value="%{feedbackFor}"></s:hidden>
<!--<s:hidden name="feedbackFor.[%{#stat.index}].positiveFeedback" value="%{positiveFeedback}"></s:hidden>-->
<td><s:textfield name="feedbackFor[%{#stat.index}].positiveFeedback" value="%{positiveFeedback}" size="100"/></td>
<td><s:textfield name="feedbackFor[%{#stat.index}].negetiveFeedback" value="%{negetiveFeedback}" size="100"/></td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>


</table>
<s:submit value="Submit Feedback"/>
</s:form>
```

**My Action**

```
public class FeedbackAction extends ActionSupport {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private List<FeedbackDTO> feedbackFor;

private String employeeId;

public List<FeedbackDTO> getFeedbackFor() {
    return feedbackFor;
}

public void setFeedbackFor(List<FeedbackDTO> feedbackFor) {
    this.feedbackFor = feedbackFor;
}


public String getEmployeeId() {
    return employeeId;
}

public void setEmployeeId(String employeeId) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
}



public String getEmployees(){

    FeedbackHelper feedbackHelper = new FeedbackHelper();
    feedbackFor=feedbackHelper.getEmployeeList(employeeId);
    System.out.println("The feed back populated is "+ feedbackFor + "Size is "+ feedbackFor.size());
            return SUCCESS;
}

public String submitFeedback(){
    System.out.println("The feed back repopulated is "+ feedbackFor + "Size is "+ feedbackFor.size());
    return SUCCESS;
}

}
```